# Definir directorios absolutos/relativos para CMS en PHP

Tags: php, cms

Estoy re-estudiando PHP, proponiendome hacer mi propio CMS. Ya tengo un montón de cosas: sistema modular, login, etc., pero hace rato estoy parado en un problema aparentemente minúsculo: los paths!
Uso WAMP en desarrollo y CPanel en pruebas semi-producción (distintos sistemas a propósito) y se arma lío con los "c:/a/a" y los "/a/a/". Sí, parcialmente se  soluciona usando urls relativas, pero como estoy en desarrollo, al cambiar el arbol de directorio, se vuelve un problema. ¿Como hago? Armo una constante? Armo una variable? Como lo vuelvo independiente si el CMS trabaja en Windows o *NIX?

Comment: Muchos CMS utilizan un parámetro / variable / constante que representa el directorio del CMS. A partir de ahí utilizas dicha variable para componer el resto de variables. Revisa x ejemplo symfony o laravel,son buenos ejemplos

Answer (score 0):

Después de postear, me puse a pensar y es algo realmente simple. Como todas las páginas o partes de ellas **(navs, headers, footers)** las cargo a través de `require/include` según necesidad, sólo me bastó con formular en un php externo (usé el de desde donde conecto y cargo las bases de datos) las siguientes constantes:

```
define('PATH', '/');
define('CSS', PATH . 'mi/directorio/css/');
define('JS', PATH . 'mi/directorio/js/');
define('IMG', PATH . 'mi/directorio/img/');
...............
```

Y desde las paginas y/o partes de ella "llamo" a cada una de las constantes =)